# Add Custom Total to Cart's GrandTotal in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add an oversized fee for large products. Most of what that entails is a little more complicated than I want to explain here. Basically, I've built a custom function to check if the product is oversized and assign the appropriate shipping cost. However, I can't figure out how to get that value added into the grand total at check out.

Comment: what you tried until now? just give us a short code block.

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

Comment: In a development environment, I've found the call for the value that's listed in the order review and tried to backtrace it. I've added logs to try to trace where it might be going. I've even hardcoded values in where I think it might be pulling from. I can't get the number to change.

Comment: I looked at that blog post. I tried some things out of it and nothing actually worked for me. Also, I really only want to know how to update the total at this point.